# 1000000000 nanoseconds do not appear to equal a second

Tags: java, nanotime

I am creating some magic spells, and obviously I want a delay between each usage.

Now [According to google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHFX_enGB521GB521&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=nanoseconds%20in%20a%20second), there are 1000000000 nanoseconds in a second.

However, the magic spell is recharging after less than two seconds.

```
@EventHandler
public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e){
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    if (p.getItemInHand().getType().equals(Material.BLAZE_ROD)){
        {
            {
                if (!kam.containsKey(p.getName())) kam.put(p.getName(), (long) 0);
                if (kam.get(p.getName()) < System.nanoTime()){
                    kam.remove(p.getName());
                    kam.put(p.getName(), System.nanoTime() + (1000000000 * 30));
                    //Do magic spell attack here.
                    }
                }
            }else{
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Skill recharging!");
            }
}
```

Obviously my code is trying to add the `System.nanoTime()` plus 30 seconds, and then checking if the current system `nanoTime` is greater than the one I put into the hashmap, and if it is, do the spell.

Comment: `1000000000 * 30` is certainly causing an integer overflow. Try with `1000000000L * 30`

Comment: There seems little point in using `nanoTime` for calculations of this magnitude. If you don't really need to measure to the nearest thousand-millionth of a second then just use `currentTimeMillis`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you print out the value `1000000000 * 30` and check it. You'll find it's wrapping around because it's too big to fit into an integer.

In other words, the following program:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println(1000000000 * 30);
        System.out.println(1000000000L * 30);
    }
}
```

prints out:

```
-64771072
30000000000
```

So, if you use the `long` variant, it will work fine.

Comment: Hang on, I have been programming since I was 11 and I didn't know that L at the end of a number turned it into a long? Wow.
Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

bare numeric literals in Java are treated as `int`s, and thus your calculation [overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). One way to fix this is to perform the calculation with `long` literals, by adding `L` after the literal:

```
kam.put(p.getName(), System.nanoTime() + (1000000000L * 30L));
```